# Android: How to add button below the listview

Tags: android

I bind the data from array-list to Listview as below:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView lstView = getListView();       
        lstView.setChoiceMode(2); 

        ArrayList<String> listTODO = PrepareList();
        lv_arr = (String[]) listTODO.toArray(new String[0]);        
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, lv_arr));
        lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     }

    private ArrayList<String> PrepareList() {
    ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    todoItems.add("AAA");
    todoItems.add("BBB");
    todoItems.add("CCC");
    todoItems.add("DDD");
    return todoItems;
    }
```

And the ListView have set multi-selected. I want to get the text have been selected on that Listview after button hv been clicked.
Anybody can help me to put the button below that ListView. I can't figure it out how to put the button coz it's didn't have the xml layout file.
.

Answer (score 0):

add after super.onCreate
listView.setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_layout_for_listview)
take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can use a xml layout and out a button under the listview element. The only thing to make sure is to have a listview element with it

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Answer (score 0):

the line `android:layout_weight="0.5"` in ListView is very important.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button            
        android:id="@+id/myBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textSize="18dip" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

if you do not have xml layout, add these controls to a LinearLayout and set layout_weight in code like the following lines:

```
LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.5f);
myBtn.setLayoutParams(param);
```